# How to store my JSON data in Ck Editor

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, ckeditor

Here is my code and its not print or display my json data in ckeditor

```
function getRules(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "api",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                version:'0.1'   
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response.data.recordslist.RulesDetails);
              CKEDITOR.instances.txtEdit.setData(response.data.recordslist.RulesDetails);
                   },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //swal("Error!", "Please try again", "error");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: use jquery code like this -> $('textarea_id').html(response);

Comment: in ajax functions? @AbdulAhmadMatin

Comment: Yes .in success:function

Comment: wont work @AbdulAhmadMatin

Comment: post all of your code to help you ajax function can't run automatically it work onclick,onkeyup or other.

Comment: i just call this function on page load @AbdulAhmadMatin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173556/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-mehul-jariwala).

Answer (score 0):

If Your URL is correct and you have URL by the name of **api** only edit success function to

```
success:function(response){ $('#txtEdit').text(response); }
```

this show a result in array you need to extract the array. 
if you don't want to extract the array. remove

```
dataType: "json"
```

it work fine. and write the data in text editor.